# How would I get articles from a certain category and its children?

Tags: mysql, select, join

I'm developing an article system that uses categories and child categories.

Basically, if the category has a `parent_id` value, it's a child of that category.

I would like to be able to get the most recent articles from a category and articles from its child categories.

For example: I have a category called "Gaming Articles" and several child categories under that called Xbox, PlayStation, Nintendo, and PC. My system makes it possible to post articles in the parent categories such as Gaming Articles as well as in the child categories.

So this would have to include articles that are in either the parent category or the child categories of that parent.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `article_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `modification_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(125) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `date_posted` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `attachment_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article_categories` (
  `category_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `attachment_id` text NOT NULL,
  `enable_comments` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `enable_ratings` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The query I have so far...

```
SELECT article_id, category_id
FROM articles
WHERE category_id = 1
ORDER BY article_id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Of course, this only gets articles under that category, not from both the category and that category's child categories.

Comment: Could you please give a graphical example of what you want?, actually i don't understand what you want...

Comment: Are you categories and child categories stored in the same table?

Comment: Yes, any row in 'article_categories' that doesn't have a parent_id of 0 is considered a child or subcategory.  I want to get articles that have a certain category id and also articles from that category's subcategories.

Comment: Are the tables 'article_categories' and 'articles' related ?

Comment: How many generations of categories are possible? I mean, say you have a child category. Can this child have one parent, which is a child of another category itself?

Comment: Is there a maximum depth of categories - ie can child categories themselves be parents of other categories? If so, what is the maximum depth? If not, is there a reasonable limit that would be acceptable?

Comment: What I love is when someone comes after me to ask the same exact question but in proper english...

Comment: can you post some sample data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your table structure stands, this query will work assuming only 1 level of nesting (ie children don't themselves have children):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM articles a
JOIN article_categories ac ON a.category_id = ac.category_id
WHERE 1 IN (a.category_id, ac.parent_id)
ORDER BY a.article_id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Note the "reversed" style `IN` to neatly capture what is effectively an `OR`.

If your nesting is deeper, simply add another join for each level, for example if you have up to 4 levels (2 more than the above query):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM articles a
JOIN article_categories ac1 ON a.category_id = ac1.category_id
LEFT JOIN article_categories ac2 ON ac1.parent_id = ac2.category_id
LEFT JOIN article_categories ac3 ON ac2.parent_id = ac3.category_id
WHERE 1 IN (a.category_id, ac1.parent_id, ac2.parent_id, ac3.parent_id
ORDER BY a.article_id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

In the second case, the use of left joins is necessary to still return articles that don't have so many levels above.

Answer (score 3):

In this structure is inposible in one query. (I assume that there are many levels of categories)

You can:

- recursively search child categories (ex. in php) and then

  SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category_id IN ( $categories );
- change db structure and use tree structure
  try: The Nested Set Model in article : http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/
- add new column to categories table, and store full path to category, ex.:

  category 1->2, category_path 1,2 
  category 1->2->3, category_path 1,2,3
  category 1->4, new category_path 1,4

If You looking all data in category 1 and children, try:

```
SELECT 
    a.* 
FROM articles a
INNER JOIN categories c
    ON a.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE c.category_path LIKE '1,%'
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as i understand, what you want is to get all the articles from a child of a category, if that is correct, try this out:

```
SELECT a.article_id, a.category_id FROM articles as a, article_categories c  WHERE a.category_id = c.category_id AND c.parent_id = (SELECT c.parent_id WHERE c.category_id = 1) ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT 10
```

If this wasn't what you wanted, comment it, i'll try to answer you.